# Video processing: Efficient way to apply function to pixel time stack (FIJI's Intensity Z-projection)

Tags: image-processing, map, video

Starting from a `Video`, I would like to apply a function `f` to the stacks of intensity values, over time, for each pixel. In *FIJI ImageJ* this would be called a ["Intensity Z-projection"](https://imagej.net/imaging/z-functions).

**I want an efficient function of the form `videoProjection[v_Video,f_ ]` that returns an `Image` where each pixel is the result of `f` applied to lists of pixel values in the time axis.**

For example, I want to get an image where each pixel is the minimum (`Min`) intensity at that pixel position over all frames, by using `videoProjection[Min, Video["ExampleData/Caminandes.mp4"]]`.

It seems to me this is not what [`VideoMapList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VideoMapList.html) offers, as this applies the function to image frames, but I want to apply the function normal to the frame, on the time axis.

If using [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), I can take advantage of the "VideoData" element. In this example, I  [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html), extract the green channel, and use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html), but this seems far from elegant or efficient.

```
minimg=Image@MapAt[
    Min,
    Transpose[
        Normal@Import[videoPath,{"AVI","VideoData"}]
        ,{4,2,3,1}
    ][[2]]
    ,{All,All}
]
```

Surely I am missing some built-in function.

## Edit

This is the best I can come up with so far, which is not the kind of solution I was expecting.

```
ClearAll[videoProjection,v,f];
videoProjection[f_Function|f_Symbol, v_Video] := Image@MapAt[
          f,
          Total@Transpose[
               VideoMapList[ImageData[#Image]&, v]
               ,{4,2,3,1}
               ],
          {All,All}
]
```

I would have expected there is something like `VideoData` instead of having to do `VideoMapList[ImageData[#Image]&, video]`.
I would also like to have a better way to deal with the pixel value, other than `Total`.

Comment: It seems there is no `VideoData`, similar to `ImageData`, is there?

Comment: I think VideoData would be: ```VideoData = (VideoExtractFrames[#, All] &)/*Map[ImageData]```